# ¿como puedo leer una matriz en zig zag comenzando desde la diagonal secundaria?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer que los lea en forma diagonal. asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He logrado que la matriz recorra a partir desde la diagonal inversa, pero siempre de arriba hacia abajo....necesito que suba y baje como se ve en la imagen.

Esto es lo que intenté hasta ahora:

```
System.out.println("");
for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
    for(int j=mat.length-1, l=i; l<mat.length; j--, l++){
        System.out.print(mat[l][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arreglo = { {1,2,25}, {8,24,26}, {23,27,28} };
    int x = arreglo.length-1;
    int y = 0;
    int i = 0;
    boolean abajo = true;
    int[] resultado = new int[(arreglo.length*(arreglo.length+1))/2];
    do{
        resultado[i++] = arreglo[x][y];
        System.out.println(String.format("(x:%d,y:%d)=%d", x,y,arreglo[x][y]));
        if (y==(arreglo[0].length-1) && abajo){
            x++; abajo=false;
        } else if (x==(arreglo.length-1) && !abajo){
            y++; abajo=true;
        } else if (abajo){
            x--; y++;
        } else {
            x++; y--;
        }
    }while (x<arreglo.length);

}
```

Eso te da el corrido indicado

Comment: No es una solución general, sólo funciona para matrices de 3x3.

Comment: @manduinca ¿contento o tengo que implementar escaneo de la matriz por ocr y una gui en JavaFX para el resultado? ;) funciona perfectamente para matrizes n*n.

Comment: @manduinca disculpa, me di cuenta que la talla funciona mucho mejor si guardo la edición ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si la matriz es de tamaño n y la llamamos A.

```
for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    int j = 0;
    if(k % 2 == 0)
        for(int i = k; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i][n - 1 - j]);
            j++;
        }
    else
        for(int i = k; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[n - 1 - j][i]);
            j++;
        }
}
```

Comment: No hace nada para n<=0 y tira `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` para n>0. Que me perdí?